# How can you turn off request validation in IIS Express?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-express

I have always been able to turn off request validation on IIS and cassini when  I need to post HTML from an HTML Editor. Problem is I can't seem to do so on IIS express. Have tried the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false"

<system.web>
<pages  validateRequest="false">
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Dang it, now I need to replace my avatar... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could try to change the web.config like this:

```
<system.web>
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

(more info here: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes)

Comment: I get: Parser Error Message: Unrecognized element 'httpRuntime'.

Comment: Ahh no I don't. Thanks found the issue